# Chess tactics #5: Yugra Governor's cup

Tags: tactics, problems

I took this position from a game that has been played today at the Yugra Governor's Cup between GM Aleksej Aleksandrov from Belarus and GM Ivan Bukavshin from Russia. White (Aleksandrov) has just played 27. Rc2 and that's a huge blunder. **How did Bukavshin win the game?**

```
[fen "1r6/5kpp/3qpb2/1Bpb4/8/5N1P/1PR1QPP1/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Bad_Bishop is almost correct, and this illustrates a general pattern in chess tactics: if a sequence of moves almost works, try changing the move order:

> 1 ... Bxf3! 2. gxf3 Rxb5 3. Qxb5 Qd1+ winning the rook, or 2. Qxf3 Rxb5 winning a piece.

Answer (score 2):

This is my gut feeling:

> 1... Rxb5 2. Qxb5 Bxf3 3. gxf3 Qd1+ 4. K moves Qxc2. Black ends up a piece ahead.

Comment: Good try but not the best continuation. White is not forced to take on f3. There is a stronger one.