# Chess tactics #6: Yugra Governor's cup again

Tags: tactics, problems

The one that I posted yesterday [Chess tactics #5: Yugra Governor's cup](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/chess-tactics-5-yugra-governors-cup) wasn't the only blunder that happened yesterday in this tournament. In the game between Alexey Sarana (2426) and GM Pavel Ponkratov (2604) the following position was reached:

```
[fen "5rk1/1bn1q1bp/p2p4/2pP1P2/1rB5/2NQ2BP/RP3PK1/5R2 w - - 0 1"]
```

White has just played 25. exf5. **How did Ponkratov win the game?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like

> 1. ... Bxc3 2. Qxc3 Rxc4 picks up a piece, because Qxc4 loses the queen to Bxd5+.

Comment: White can also recapture with the pawn (2. bxc3) but this does not make a difference.